# Override S3 endpoint using Boto3 configuration file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, botocore

#### OVERVIEW:

I'm trying to override certain variables in `boto3` using the configuration file (`~/aws/confg`).
In my use case I want to use `fakes3` service and send S3 requests to the localhost.

#### EXAMPLE:

In `boto` (not `boto3`), I can create a config in `~/.boto` similar to this one:

```
[s3]
host = localhost
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat

[Boto]
is_secure = False
```

And the client can successfully pick up desired changes and instead of sending traffic to the real S3 service, it will send it to the localhost.

```
>>> import boto
>>> boto.connect_s3()
S3Connection:localhost
>>>
```

#### WHAT I TRIED:

I'm trying to achieve a similar result using `boto3` library. By looking at the source code I found that I can use `~/aws/config` location. I've also found an example config in `unittests` folder of `botocore`.

I tried to modify the config to achieve the desired behaviour.  But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Here is the config:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
region = us-east-1
is_secure = False
s3 =
    host = localhost
```

#### QUESTION:

1. How to overwrite `clients` variables using config file?
2. Where can I find a complete list of allowed variables for the configuration?

Comment: May be it's an update but we can do this if we are using python 2: boto.connect_s3(
  aws_access_key_id=[ACCESS KEY], 
  aws_secret_access_key=[SECRET KEY], 
  host='localhost', 
  port=4572, 
  is_secure=True, 
  calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()
)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You cannot set host in config file, however you can override it from your code with boto3.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session()

s3_client = session.client(
    service_name='s3',
    aws_access_key_id='aaa',
    aws_secret_access_key='bbb',
    endpoint_url='http://localhost',
)
```

Then you can interact as usual.

```
print(s3_client.list_buckets())
```

Comment: This works great but boto3 is not supported in `gsutils` boto configuration (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil). Any alternative in that case?

Answer (score 15):

`boto3` only reads the signature version for s3 from that config file. You may want to open a feature request, but for now here is how you can address a custom endpoint:

```
import boto3
from botocore.utils import fix_s3_host
resource = boto3.resource(service_name='s3', endpoint_url='http://localhost')
resource.meta.client.meta.events.unregister('before-sign.s3', fix_s3_host)
```

That bit about the meta is important because `boto3` automatically changes the endpoint to `your_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com` when it sees fit [1](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/utils.py#L624). If you'll be working with both your own host and s3, you may wish to override the functionality rather than removing it altogether.

Comment: how can i do that for sns?

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
import boto3

s3client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://X.X.x.X:8080/',
        aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXX',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXXXXX')
bucket_name = 'aaaaa'
s3client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

Comment: Is the trailing slash and port of the end point url required?

Comment: You do not need specify port if you hit AWS S3.

Comment: Isn't that essentially just this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327767/17676984) ? And [please do not post an answer that consists essentially of code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem, when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 7):

using boto3 resource:

```
import boto3

# use third party object storage
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url='https://URL:443',
  aws_access_key_id = 'AccessKey',
  aws_secret_access_key = 'SecertKey')

# Print out bucket names
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
 print(bucket.name)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
s3_client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    "us-east-1",
    aws_access_key_id="test_id",
    aws_secret_access_key="test_key",
    endpoint_url="https://localhost:7000",
    use_ssl=True,
    verify=False,
)
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially just this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327767/17676984) plus a few keyword arguments ? And [please do not post an answer that consists essentially of code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem, when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Devil is in the details. This is a complete answer. 
Those "few keyword arguments" make a difference in whether the code will work. I thought posting a complete answer to supplement a partial answer is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've just submitted a PR to boto3 to add an env var to allow you to override the endpoint_url if you need to use a dependent module which uses boto3 (in which case you may not be able to modify the call to boto3.client directly)

https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/2746

https://github.com/rwillmer/boto3